# Finding marginal PMF of a trinomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, marginal-distribution

> **Problem:** A fair six-sided die is rolled 30 independent times, let $X$ be the number of ones and $Y$ the number of twos. Find the marginal PMF $P_Y(y)$ of $Y$.

Let $X=n, Y=m$, then the joint PMF is $$P_{X,Y}(x,y)=\binom{N}{n} \binom{N-n}{m} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n+m} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{N-n-m}$$

> Question: I know $P_Y(y)$ is of the form $\sum P_{X,Y}(x,y)$, but I am not sure how to represent $x$ and do the algorithm here..

Comment: $Y$ has binomial distribution $B(30, 1/6)$.

Comment: @NCh but how do we represent n and m independently since they are not specified?